# Why is my local notification not launching at the desired time or at all

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (IBAction)hitAlarm:(id)sender {
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

NSDateFormatter *formatter;
NSString        *dateString;

formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"];

dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:_timePicker.date];
NSLog(@"%@",dateString);


[localNotif setFireDate:_timePicker.date];
[localNotif setRepeatInterval:NSCalendarUnitDay];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
NSLog(@"Hit Button");
}
```

This is a method to set an alarm that will create a local notification at a specified time. However, when the time comes when it should have created a notification, it appears that it did not. There are no given error messages it simply does not seem to deliver a notification. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

On iOS8, you must call `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];` to get permissions to display background notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're obliged to provide the alert body in order to show a notification. This is what I've found in the documentation:

> Assign a string or, preferably, a localized-string key (using NSLocalizedString) as the value of the message. If the value of this property is non-nil, an alert is displayed

You DO NOT set any alert body, therefore it is nil, therefore you don't see the notification

And of course you have to register notification settings as `algal` said